# Longest consecutive sequence of an element not appearing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Say I have a string only containing “A”, “B” and “C”.

For example, “ABBCAABBCABBBCBBA”.

How do I find the longest substring such that the substring does not contain “A”?

I know that itertools.groupby() can be used to find longest consecutive sequence of an element, but how do I adapt this to find the longest sequence such that an element isn’t present?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using your `itertools.groupby` solution, by passing it a `key` function that checks for equality with "A".

Comment: How exactly does this work? Why would I check equality with “A”?

Comment: @theman Because for the purpose of grouping, you only care that a character is "not A", `key` allows you to group by some other criteria besides exact character matching, in this case, create an iterator grouped into A's and not A's.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the string by using a regex expression such as this one :

```
([^A])+
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/K391Oa/1).

And getting the matching group with the biggest `len()` value.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method would be a single pass, stepping through each element and adding it to the "current" substring if it isn't an "A" and then just keeping track of the longest substring found.

Alternatively, you could just `.split("A")` and get the longest substring in the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as the largest distance between two substrings. The code below does this by splitting the main_str on the sub_str, and then finding the longest result of the split.

```
max(main_str.split(sub_str), key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the itertools package but if you'd like to take a somewhat inelegant but straightforward approach, you could use list comprehensions quite profitably. Here is some code I threw together quickly that represents this approach:

```
letters="ABBCAABBCABBBCBBA"
targets=[i for i in range(len(letters)) if letters[i]=='A']
distances=[targets[i]-targets[i-1] -1 for i in range(1,len(targets))]
print(max(distances))
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `NumPy` as:

```
string = 'ABBCAABBCABBBCBBA'
arr = np.append(np.where([string[i] == 'A' for i in range(len(string))])[0]+1, len(string))
arr[1:] -= arr[:-1].copy()+1
print(max(arr[1:]))
```